# How to receive MWS notifications with Rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-mws

I'm searching for a solution how to receive Amazon MWS notifications at a Rabbitmq instance. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, notifications can only be sent to an Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) queue.

source: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/subscriptions/Subscriptions_ReceivingNotifications.html

Comment: Thanks, I know that already. I've hoped, that someone has developed an alternative or workaround to use Rabbitmq instead of Amazon SQS.

Comment: write a process to pull from SQS and then send to Rabbitmq...That's the only thing I can think of if that's your goal.   I've been pulling notifications from SQS for the last year or so and they said over a year ago the same thing.  Amazon wants you to use their stuff!  I get it :)